# How to set xframe options properly to display a pdf

Tags: django, x-frame-options

So I get this error when trying to render a pdf in html with

Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

I already tried

1. Setting X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
2. Using @xframe_options_sameorigin as decorator to my view
3. Removed the xframe package in the settings

nothing seems to work so I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some more research and what worked for me was:

Doing a **hard reload** from the webpage:

This clears the cache which often causes issues in development
https://www.sunilchauhan.com/learn/what-does-ctrl-shift-r-do-in-chrome/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).